# Join two mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables:

Table1

```
RouteID             int
departure_stop      int 
destination_stop    int 
Price               decimal(6,2)
```

Table2

```
StopID          int
Stop            varchar(50)
Cities_CityID   int
```

Table3

```
CityID      int
City        varchar(50)
```

I want to get all Routes which are cheaper than 50. 
I want get departure city and destination city like this

```
City    City
Paris   London
Madrid  Zagred
```

So far I have dove two queries I am getting departure city and then second query for destination city, but don't know how join them side by side. Here are my queries:

```
SELECT
    Cities.City
FROM Routes, Stops, Cities
WHERE (Stops.StopID = Routes.departure_stop AND Stops.Cities_CityID = Cities.CityID AND Routes.price < '50')
```

And

```
SELECT
    Cities.City
FROM Routes, Stops, Cities
WHERE (Stops.StopID = Routes.destination_stop AND Stops.Cities_CityID = Cities.CityID AND Routes.price < '50')
```

So the question is how to join them together side by side so I could see departure and destination?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
    DepartureCity.City AS 'Departure City',
    DestinationCity.City AS 'Destination City'
FROM Routes
INNER JOIN Stops DepartureStop    ON DepartureStop.StopID   = Routes.departure_stop
INNER JOIN Stops DestinationStop  ON DestinationStop.StopID = Routes.destination_stop 
INNER JOIN Cities DepartureCity   ON DepartureCity.CityID   = DepartureStop.Cities_CityID 
INNER JOIN Cities DestinationCity ON DepartureCity.CityID   = DestinationStop.Cities_CityID 

WHERE Routes.price < 50
```

Comment: Thank you it works! Looks complicated but I'll try to figure it out

Comment: It's not that complicated. Just start from the route, then join the end tables for the departure and destination and then join the cities to these two stops each. If you're happy, please accept the answer that suits you. Cheers